# Print a value in R and format size and color

Tags: r, datatable, rstudio

I have calculated a value X based on a table and want to print and formatize (size and color) the value X now. So it should be displayed like a numeric point in a dashboard. Is there a way to display it like I described?

PS: I don't want the classic console.log in R but the display in the Viewer.

Comment: Hi, I think there may be some relevant information missing from your question. What exactly do you mean by "the Viewer"? R it self doesn't have a "viewer". Are you using something like shiny, rmarkdown, jupyter, datatable, [...], to display your output?

Comment: Yes, I am using RStudio and there u have a window next to the console which is called "viewer" which displays the table/visualization etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm afraid I can't help you with that (I never use that part of RStudio). It might help to add the RStudio tag to your question so that people who _can_ help can find it easier …

Comment: The Viewer pane is used to display HTML-based output within RStudio. It's still unclear on what you're asking for, however. Are you asking on how to build a shiny app?

Comment: Yes, I want to display a HTML-based output that's correct. So I have created a variable x=11.5%. I want now to display x in the viewer pane. Thats all i want.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots or code to reproduce?